# ASP.NET MVC5 support for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing in VS2012, and just downloaded the MVC 5 with WebApi2 support.

Problem I see is when creating a new "MVC5 Empty Project", I don't get the option to choose the API2 template any longer.

I used to be able to do this in VS2012. In other words, I would create a new MVC 4 Project, then get the following dialog box with template options :

[image]

Do I need to manually add the API2 package now via NuGet Package Manager ?

Thanks in advance.

Bob

Comment: I have the same problem. Seems like someone would have chimed in by now.

Comment: @jeff - I ended up going with MVC 4 at the time, hoping to move up to VS2015 at some point soon. MVC4 is fine for what I'm doing because my app is AngularJS-based.

Comment: I finally got a solution.  After about a week of looking at many different tutorials (where the template was always different than what I had) I finally saw a solution somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got a solution.  Use VS2013 Web Express for latest templates and generate scaffolded projects.  Then go back to VS2012 and open the projects.